# How to separate different parts of a a non-monolithic application in VCSs?

Tags: python, mercurial, project-management, setup-project

We've got a pretty large project which consists of multiple different sub-projects. Each sub-project is being controlled on a `mercurial` repository. Recently I found it annoying that a new developer should clone lots of repositories (and probably configure them) to get started.

What is a good approach to have both the concern separation and a good learning curve?

The dominant language of our codes is Python.
Examples of good (open source) project structures could help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial offers [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository). This feature, however, has its limitations and is seen as a [feature of last resort](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FeaturesOfLastResort).

That wiki page has a [section](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Alternatives) describing alternatives. There's a relatively young extension called [Hg Guest Repo](https://bitbucket.org/selinc/guestrepo) that tries to address some of the limitations of subrepositories.